# Convert AJAX request into HTTP request in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

Actually i am using ajax call to connect to a 3rd party api when i am using the api on browser and i am able to get the data from the api.
Here is the AJAX code:-

```
var settings = {
  async: true,
  //crossDomain: true,
  url: "https://rest.cricketapi.com/rest/v2/schedule/?access_token=XXX"
  //"url": "https://rest.cricketapi.com/rest/v2/match/indaus_2020_one-day_02/?access_token=XXX"
  //bblt20_2019_g28
};

//create token for the api for 24hours
let token;
function getToken() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://rest.cricketapi.com/rest/v2/auth/",
    data: {
      access_key: "********************************",
      secret_key: "********************************",
      app_id: "http://localhost:8000/",
      device_id: "developer"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);

      token = data.auth.access_token;
      console.log(token,);
      //do something when request is successfull
      createUpcomingMatchesSchedule();
    },
    dataType: "json"
  });
}

function createUpcomingMatchesSchedule() {
  var urlJson = settings.url;
  urlJson = urlJson.replace(/XXX/g, token);
  settings.url = urlJson;

  $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    toGetUpcomingMatches(response);
  });
}
```

Now i want to convert this ajax method into http request so that i can use the data on the server using nodejs.
Here is the code:-

```
const { db } = require("../../utility/admin");
var request = require("request");

// //*************************** API INITIALIZATION ********************************

var settings = {
  async: true,
  //crossDomain: true,
  url: "https://rest.cricketapi.com/rest/v2/schedule/?access_token=XXX"
  //"url": "https://rest.cricketapi.com/rest/v2/match/indaus_2020_one-day_02/?access_token=XXX"
  //bblt20_2019_g28
};

var options = {
  method: "POST",
  // hostname: "https://rest.cricketapi.com",
  uri: "https://rest.cricketapi.com/rest/v2/auth/",
  access_key: "********************************",
  secret_key: "********************************",
  app_id: "http://localhost:8000/",
  device_id: "developer"
};

let token;
function getToken() {
  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log(body);
      token = body.auth.access_token;
      console.log(token);
      // console.log(response);
    }
  });
}

module.exports = { getToken };
```

But i am not able to access the data from the api when i am using the nodejs code.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What issue are you facing? Are you getting any error?

Comment: The API you use has documentation for nodejs developers. You probably should follow it. jQuery sets many http request headers for you, like `Accept` and `Content-Type`. It also constructs the POST payload and its `Content-Length` header value for you.All that stuff gets handled in different ways from nodejs.

Comment: @O. Jones Actually in their api they use curl commands. They don't have nodejs commands. For web i have converted their curl command into ajax call but now i want to use the api for server side.

Comment: @KAMLESHKUMAR No Error i am getting but i am not getting the response from the api.

Comment: I've been add my answer, you can check it out and test it. I hope it can help you.

Comment: https://www.cricketapi.com/docs/guides/Open-Source-Libraries/#nodejs-library examples for nodejs.

Comment: And, check this:  https://rapidapi.com/er.jaideepghosh/api/cricketapi3

Answer (score -1):

‍ **For an example**, you can look at this code below:

```js
var options = {
  method: "POST",
  // hostname: "https://rest.cricketapi.com",
  uri: "https://rest.cricketapi.com/rest/v2/auth/",
  // make sure, on this API, use body or headers. 
  // If body, you can change this `headers` to `form`.
  headers: { 
    access_key: "********************************",
    secret_key: "********************************",
    app_id: "http://localhost:8000/",
    device_id: "developer"
  }
};

let token;
function getToken() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) return reject(error) 
      body = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log(body);
      token = body.auth.access_token;
      return resolve(token);
    });
  })
}
```

I hope it can help you .

Comment: Out of interest, why have you started putting emojis in your answers? It seems... distracting. (I didn't downvote).

Comment: It's ok. I think it's annoying and whether it depends on how someone judges it. As for me, there is no more or less. That's just ordinary. For downvote, I make some mistake from my answer before, then I just updated it.

Comment: You think it's annoying, so you put them in?

Comment: No, I mean, it's annoying or not depends on who judges it.

Comment: I think it's accepted that [emojis are considered noise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172146/284827) so shouldn't be in posts.

Comment: If only text, there's no expresion, It's like you talk to someone but he doesn't pay attention to you. But thank you for saying that. I really appreciate it. But one for you, we don't have to expect what we do to be liked by others. I'm sorry, my english so bad, because I'm using google translate.

Comment: I am getting this error: {
>    status: false,
>    cachekey: null,
>    version: '2.0.2',
>    status_code: 403,
>    status_msg: 'Missing Credentials',
>    expires: '-1',
>    Etag: null,
>    data: null
>  }
>  C:\Users\Aman\Desktop\Predicta_Project\Predicta-Cloud-Functions\functions\handlers\LiveScoring\scoring.js:35
>        token = body.auth.access_token;
>                          ^
>
>  TypeError: Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined @Titus Sutio Fanpula

Comment: I'm just convert your Ajax to request. Make sure the data you send ia pass into body or headers. I've give a comment there. From your errors, there's missing credential. You can changed headers to form In options.